# Second authorization with same scope and offline access_type has unexpected permission dialog

Tags: google-drive-api

If I specify access_type=offline in the auth url and a user attempts to auth a second time I get a box that says it is asking for offline access.

I would have expected it to be already authorised and so not require additional permissions

Any ideas?

Edit:

A bit more info. The first time around it makes no mention to the user of needing offline access. I would have thought the offline permission to be mentioned in the original auth anyway.

Edit 2:

Some more info on my use case. It is possible in our system for a person to have two accounts but then use the same google drive account. This means that we have no way of knowing that user has already authorized with google and so have to present the authorization again for the second user.

The first time around (for user 1) you are told that the app is asking for :

> View and manage Google Drive files that you have opened or created
>   with this app
>
> View and manage the files and documents in your Google
>   Drive

The second time around (for user 2) you are told the app is asking to:

> Have offline access

This seems wrong to me.

As an aside:

The whole "have offline access" statement is very confusing for a user and also quite misleading. Most people assume this means the app can read the contents of your pc. In fact it means that the app can authenticate with your account with out you being there (i.e. using a refresh token).