# Opening file from google drive always requests offline access

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a google drive application that does not request offline access and is already installed and authorised by the user. If the application requests authorisation itself, there are no problems.

However, recently, every time a file is opened from the Google Drive UI, an authorisation prompt appears:

```
This app would like to:
Have offline access
```

Oking this request will still mean it appears the next time a file is opened. I can see in the url that Google Drive generates that it requests "access_type: offline". I see no settings in the cloud console to control this and its very confusing for users. How can it be prevented?

I see a number of similar questions but not quite like this:

[How to disable offline OAuth2 access from Google Drive SDK initiated connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181516/how-to-disable-offline-oauth2-access-from-google-drive-sdk-initiated-connections)

[Second authorization with same scope and offline access_type has unexpected permission dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882527/second-authorization-with-same-scope-and-offline-access-type-has-unexpected-perm)

["This app would like to: Have offline access" when access_type=online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405274/this-app-would-like-to-have-offline-access-when-access-type-online)

[The App keeps asking for permission to "Have offline access", why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097008/the-app-keeps-asking-for-permission-to-have-offline-access-why?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution for this.
This message will keep appearing if you don't do step2 of the OAuth2 flow with the same client_id and client_secret.

```
@app.route('/open')
def drive_open_file():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    if code:
        credentials = credentials_from_code("client", "secret",
                               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                               code,
                               redirect_uri="<WEBSITE>/open")
```